# “Cannot read property 'ajax of undefined”

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatables

I want to refresh the table after click search and this is happen, 
here is the table

```
methods: {
  init: function() {
    appTable = $('#tblApproval').DataTable({
      ajax : {
        url: '{{ Route("api_travel_app_list") }}',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        data: function(d) {
          d.period = appSearch.period;
          d.status = appSearch.status;
        },
        beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
          doLoading(true);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log("Text Status: " + textStatus + ", Error: " + errorThrown);
          swal(textStatus, errorThrown, "error");
        },
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus)  {
          doLoading(false);
        }
      },
      columns: [
        {
          data: null,
          render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
            return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
          }
        },
```

and here is the error code

```
open: function() {
    $("#modalSearch").modal("show");
    this.fetchComboBoxData();
  },
  search: function() {
    if(appSearch.nik == ""){
      swal({
        imageUrl: "{{ asset('asset/img/icon/png/malware.png') }}",
        imageHeight: 110,
        text: 'NIK should not be empty',
        showCloseButton: true
      });
      return;
    }

    appTable.ajax.reload();
    $("#modalSearch").modal("toggle");
```

In this code I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined.

Comment: What is `appTable`? Evidently it's `undefined`, but it isn't mentioned anywhere else in your code except the line that's failing.

Comment: Edited please help

Comment: just console.log(appTable)

Comment: the console says undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a reactive property and assign your `DataTable` to it.

```
data: {
    appTable: null
}
```

or if it's a component, use function instead

```
data: function() {
    return {
        appTable: null
    }
}
```

More about `data` property you can read here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods

In your `init` method you should replace `appTable = $('#tblApproval').DataTable` with `this.appTable = $('#tblApproval').DataTable`. And in your `search` method `appTable.ajax.reload();` to

```
if(this.appTable) {
    this.appTable.ajax.reload();
}
else {
    console.log('The data table was not loaded!');
}
```

Also, it's obvious, that your `init` function should be initialized before you call a `search`. May be you should place it in `created` hook if you didn't already.

```
created: function() {
    this.init();
}
```

More about lifecycle hooks you can read here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks

Comment: After added your suggested code. there is a errror "TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function"
and the apptable is not loaded

Comment: @Aiubay do you include `DataTable` actually?

Comment: What does that mean ?

Comment: @Aiubay Include it through the cdn or import as a module https://datatables.net/manual/installation

Comment: oh yeah i do include `DataTable`

Comment: @Aiubay and jquery? Also, try to output `$('#tblApproval')`

Comment: the output is `n.fn.init [table#tblOvertime.table.table-bordered.table-striped, context: document, selector: "#tblOvertime"]` i change the tblApproval to tblOvertime

Comment: @Aiubay there is an issue with `DataTable` not being properly appended to your element, not a `vue.js` problem anymore.